# Call to undefined method Laravel\Passport\Passport::routes() while upgrading laravel-passport

Tags: laravel-passport, laravel-10

I upgraded laravel to 10 and also updated "laravel/passport": "^10.4" to "laravel/passport": "^11.0".

It throws error in AuthServiceProvider while executing composer update.

````
     20▕
     21▕         /** @var CachesRoutes $app */
     22▕         $app = $this->app;
     23▕         if (!$app->routesAreCached()) {
  ➜  24▕             Passport::routes(null, ['prefix' => 'api/oauth']);
     25▕         }
     26▕
     27▕         Passport::ignoreCsrfToken();
     28▕         Passport::hashClientSecrets();```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed `Passport::routes(null, ['prefix' => 'api/oauth']);` from AuthServiceProvider and added `'path' => 'api/oauth'` in config/passport.php

It's working now.